# extract 2 sub strings before specific substring

Tags: python, string

This is my test string:

```
J0C,DRUMMONDVILLE,QC,CDP,K2E,NEPEAN,ON,LCD,MERIVALE,K9A,COBOURG,ON,LCD,MAIN
```

Whenever I see `,ON` I need 2 words before that like

```
K2E,NEPEAN,ON,K9A,COBOURG,ON
```

Comment: Just split on `,` and use the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'J0C,DRUMMONDVILLE,QC,CDP,K2E,NEPEAN,ON,LCD,MERIVALE,K9A,COBOURG,ON,LCD,MAIN'
>>> re.findall(r'\w+,\w+,ON', s)
['K2E,NEPEAN,ON', 'K9A,COBOURG,ON']
```

If you want these rejoined using a comma separator you can use `str.join`

```
>>> ','.join(re.findall(r'\w+,\w+,ON', s))
'K2E,NEPEAN,ON,K9A,COBOURG,ON'
```

Comment: Similarly how to combine substrings if I find before ON and alphanumeric string for example: K7A,SMITHS,FALLS,ON should become  K7A,SMITHSFALLS,ON. If MIK,Toronto,ON - no need to change, F6A,NIAGARA,FALLS,STN,ON  should be F6A,NIAGARAFALLSSTN,ON

Comment: Similarly how to combine substrings if I find before ON and alphanumeric string for example: K7A,SMITHS,FALLS,ON should become K7A,SMITHSFALLS,ON. If MIK,Toronto,ON - no need to change, F6A,NIAGARA,FALLS,STN,ON should be F6A,NIAGARAFALLSSTN,ON

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution (maybe more flexible):

```
string = "J0C,DRUMMONDVILLE,QC,CDP,K2E,NEPEAN,ON,LCD,MERIVALE,K9A,COBOURG,ON,LCD,MAIN"

class Words:
    parts = []

    def __init__(self, string):
        self.parts = string.split(",")

    def search(self, needle, wordcnt=2):
        indices = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(self.parts) if item == needle]

        for index in indices:
            if index > wordcnt:
                yield self.parts[index - wordcnt:index]


haystack = Words(string)

for part in haystack.search("ON"):
    print(part)
```

Which would yield

```
['K2E', 'NEPEAN']
['K9A', 'COBOURG']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
test_str = "J0C,DRUMMONDVILLE,QC,CDP,K2E,NEPEAN,ON,LCD,MERIVALE,K9A,COBOURG,ON,LCD,MAIN"
words = test_str.split(",")
i=0
words_you_want = []
for word in words:
    if word == "ON":
        words_you_want.append(words[i-2])
        words_you_want.append(words[i-1])
        words_you_want.append(word)
    i += 1
print(words_you_want)
```

Output:

```
['K2E', 'NEPEAN', 'ON', 'K9A', 'COBOURG', 'ON']
```

Comment: how apply this on pandas dataframe?